# Double scrollbar when displaying PDF in Telerik RadWindow

Tags: asp.net, iframe, telerik, scrollbar, radwindow

I have a page that displays a pdf report in a RadWindow via javascript, but for some reason it has two sets of vertical scrollbars: one created by Internet Explorer and one in the PDF itself.

I am displaying other PDF reports in the exact same fashion, the only difference between this one that I can see is that the report is loaded from a different domain(just different port in the development environment, still the same physical server either way).

This does not happen on Chrome, only on IE. And I can't even seem to get either of the scrollbars removed even using the DOM editor in IE's development tools.

I've tried giving the radwindow a CSS class which set overflow to hidden and display inline, the report page itself also has html and body with those settings.

Here is the javascript code I use to open the radwindow:

```
function showRadWindowSupply(url, title) {
var oWnd = $find("<%=_rwInvoice.ClientID%>");
oWnd.setUrl(url);
oWnd.set_title(title);
oWnd.show();
sizeRadWindowSupply(oWnd, 70, 80);
return false;
}
function sizeRadWindowSupply(oWnd, width, height) {
var browserWidth = $telerik.$(window).width();

var browserHeight = $telerik.$(window).height();
oWnd.setSize(Math.ceil(browserWidth * width / 100), Math.ceil(browserHeight * height / 100));
oWnd.center();
}
```

Here is the RadWindow markup used on the aspx page:

```
<telerik:RadWindowManager id="_rwm1" runat="server">
    <Windows>
        <telerik:RadWindow ID="_rwInvoice" runat="server" Behaviors="Close,Maximize" CssClass="holdsSplitter" AutoSize="false" VisibleStatusbar="false" Modal="true"  ></telerik:RadWindow>
    </Windows>
</telerik:RadWindowManager>
```

And here is the HTML that is generated for the RadWindow:

```
<div class="RadWindow RadWindow_Telerik rwNormalWindow rwTransparentWindow holdsSplitter" id="RadWindowWrapper_ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__rwInvoice" style="left: 204px; top: 58px; width: 957px; height: 472px; visibility: visible; position: absolute; z-index: 3001; -ms-touch-action: none; transform: none; backface-visibility: visible;" unselectable="on">
    <table class="rwTable" style="height: 433px;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr class="rwTitleRow">
                <td class="rwCorner rwTopLeft">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="rwTitlebar">
                    <div class="rwTopResize">
                        <!-- / -->
                    </div>
                    <table align="left" class="rwTitlebarControls" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 16px;"><a class="rwIcon"></a></td>
                                <td><em style="width: 847px;" unselectable="on">Supply Orders Invoice</em></td>
                                <td nowrap="" style="white-space: nowrap;">
                                    <ul class="rwControlButtons" style="width: 62px;">
                                        <li><a title="Maximize" class="rwMaximizeButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Maximize</span></a></li>
                                        <li><a title="Close" class="rwCloseButton" href="javascript:void(0);"><span>Close</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="rwCorner rwTopRight">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rwContentRow">
                <td class="rwCorner rwBodyLeft">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="rwWindowContent rwExternalContent" valign="top">
                    <iframe name="_rwInvoice" src="http://devsvr:87/Reports/StaticReports/OrderHistoryDetail.aspx?ID=1748" frameborder="0" style="border: 0px currentColor; width: 100%; height: 100%;"></iframe>
                </td>
                <td class="rwCorner rwBodyRight">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rwStatusbarRow" style="display: none;">
                <td class="rwCorner rwBodyLeft">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="rwStatusbar">
                    <table align="left" style="width: 100%;" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width: 100%;">
                                    <input tabindex="-1" class="rwLoading" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__rwInvoice_status" readonly="" unselectable="on"><label style="display: none;" for="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1__rwInvoice_status">status label</label></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </td>
                <td class="rwCorner rwBodyRight">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="rwFooterRow">
                <td class="rwCorner rwFooterLeft">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="rwFooterCenter">&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="rwCorner rwFooterRight">&nbsp;</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which is the element that has the unwanted scrollbar? If you locate it with the dev toolbar, you should be able to create a CSS selector to disable its scrollbars.

Comment: It appears that the scrollbar is within the iframe, applying any CSS rules to the iframe or setting scrolling="no" don't seem to have any effect. I've tried adding a class with overflow:hidden !important; in it to basically everything around it with no effect.

Comment: does this happen with all browsers? Judging by your iframe src you may be streaming a file like a PDF so does a different browser plugin avoid the issue?